# Change Alert Title In In-app-purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I am integrating my  iPhone app with PayPal. Now I am taking fixed amount of charge for doing this transection. If user clicks on Pay by PayPal i am asking user to first make an In-app purchase. When user is doing transection for the first there won't be any problem.

But when user has already did transection before, it will display message "You have purchased this. Tap OK to download it again for free" with "Cancel" and "OK" buttons.

I think this type of message doesn't make any sense as its not for downloading app, Can i change it to something like "You have done this transection before. Tap Ok to perform next transection" with "Cancel" and "OK" buttons.

Is there any way i can give custom title or do they have any other pre-define messages for this type of transections?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: can i know the reason of down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but probably because unclear language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way (nor is there a reason for there to be).  Furthermore Apple will reject your app if you attempt to use PayPal to purchase an In-App download.

Comment: No, I am not using PayPal to purchase an In-app download. But if user want to use PayPal service from my app,then he/she needs to do In-app purchase. Will that be okay?

Comment: I don't know, it sounds pretty cheap to me but it might be OK with the review board.

Comment: Because this message doen't make any sense. So if not change, can i at least remove that alert box if user has already paid before ?